# Can't bind to local XXXX for debugger

Tags: android

Debugger is not connected in eclipse when I open another IDE like Android Studio.
when I debug app getting message on eclipse console - "**Can't bind to local XXXX for debugger**" 
Is there any way to debug application.?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you use 2 IDE?

Comment: You should not have both the IDEs open.

Comment: ok thanks  KKD and  Randyka Yudhistira for your response so you exactly mean I can not debug application when I open two IDE. at the same time???

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Eclipse, if open. Also, Kill `"eclipse.exe"` process from TaskManager if it is still alive.
2. Open `Android Studio`. If already open restart it (just to be safe)
3. execute `adb kill-server`
4. execute `adb start-server`